# Calling magento block returning false

Tags: blocks, phtml

This probably easy and I'm forgetting something but...

product.price.final is a default xml block of magento why does it always returns false when I call it on my custom phtml.

```
<div>
  <?= $block->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.final')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
```

Obs: this is not on catalog_product_view page

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call a Magento 2 block in a custom .phtml file and it is returning false, it could be due to a few different issues:

1. The block class might not be defined correctly in the layout XML
   file. Make sure the class path and name are correct.
2. The block might not be instantiated in the layout XML file. Make
   sure the block is defined and instantiated in the layout XML file
   with the correct name.
3. The block might not have the correct template set. Make sure the
   template file path is correct and that the file exists.
4. The block might not be in the correct block group. Make sure the
   block is in the correct block group and that the group is being
   called in the **`.phtml`** file.

It is also possible that the issue is not with the block, but with the **`.phtml`** file. Make sure that the **`.phtml`** file is being called correctly in the layout XML file and that it exists in the correct location.

I suggest you to check and match the following :

- block class defined in **`layout xml`**
- block instantiation in **`layout xml`**
- block template
- block group name
- **`.phtml`** file call in layout xml

Please let me know, if you have any specific error message or any other details, I would be happy to help you with that.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Hm, Im calling the magento block directly on phtml, phtml file is not the problem since other things is being displayed.

The magento block xml is correct also since was made by magento haha'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go to app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

````
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>```
````